# Tkinter - How do I jump to a section of a large menu option list?

Tags: tkinter, optionmenu

I have a large OptionMenu list that may contain up to 500 sorted (A-Z) items or more. This makes it cumbersome/time consuming for the user to scroll through the list. Question: when the OptionMenu is open, is there a way to move the selection bar (and mouse) to a specific section of the list displayed? For example, by pressing the letter 'N', move the selection bar (and mouse) to the items starting with the letter 'N'. (Keep in mind the 'N' items may not even be visible since the menu is bounded by the height of the screen.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a ttk `combobox`
http://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#combobox